# SSIS 2017 KerberosSupport - Double Hop Issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis, kerberos, spn

I am having an issue with what appears to be a kerberos double hop issue with SSIS 2017.

The setup consists of a backend database cluster servers (DBSERVER01\02) an Application\SSIS server (APPSERVER01) and various clients connecting from other hosts with SSMS. Managed Service accounts are used for all SQL services and trusted for delegation, SPNs have been set for the MSSQL DB Service, the SQL Kerberos checker passes all tests. An SSISDB catalogue has been deployed and enabled for Always ON support, the SSIS configuration on APPSERVER01 has been updated to point to the catalogue database via the database cluster listener.

Via SSMS on the APPSERVER01 when connecting to Integration Services it works fine, when connecting form any other host the following error is received:
“The SQL Server instance specified in SSIS service configuration is not present or is not available. This might occur when there is no default instance of SQL Server on the computer. For more information, see the topic "Configuring the Integration Services Service" in %SQL_PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME% Books Online.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (MsDtsSrvr)”

Does SISS support this type of deployment? If so what am I missing?

Comment: Check out this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connect-to-a-remote-integration-services-server-ssis-service?view=sql-server-2014#by-default-the-ssis-service-does-not-support-delegation)